# Laravel returns http instead of https on production

Tags: laravel, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

On my production (aws) laravel returns http even if it is really `https`.

```
\Request::url(); // this returns http://...
\Request::isSecure()?'yes':'no'; // this returns 'no'
```

and it would not change if I force shema to http or https.
When I force schema like that:

```
\Illuminate\Support\Facades\URL::forceScheme('https');
```

the only thing that being changed is this

```
url()->current(); // this returns https://...
```

I cannot reproduce problem on my local/dev homestead, it works perfectly on homestead.

(laravel 5.7)

Comment: You could try the approach of forcing the route to use `https` such as `Route::post('post/store', ['uses' => 'PostsController@store', 'https'])->name('post.store');`.

Answer (score 0):

For any routes that you want to force https, you should wrap them in a middleware that forces a secure connection. A generic example that only does the redirect on production is shown here:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;

class HttpsProtocol {

    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
            if (!$request->secure() && env('APP_ENV') === 'production') {
                return redirect()->secure($request->getRequestUri());
            }

            return $next($request); 
    }
}
```

To apply this to your routes, you would register it wherever you assign your middleware - either as a group in the routes/web.php file, or in the App\Http\Kernel.